# How to pass values obtained from one senario to another in cucumber tests?

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I want to be able to use [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) to test the following scenario

```
Feature: test

  Scenario: Start a service 
    When I start a service
    Then I obtain a token

  Scenario: Customers join a service
    When I have a token
    Then open a url and apply the token
```

The underlying implementation is in typescript.

In the first scenario I will generate a token. With the token I want to open a specific url and use the token there.

How can I pass the token from one scenario to another?

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass value from one scenario to another. Each scenario should be considered an independent test. Try instead using a background to setup a new token for each scenario.

```
  Background: Start a service 
    When I start a service
    Then I obtain a token

  Scenario: Customers join a service
    When I have a token
    Then open a url and apply the token
```

Or better yet push `start a service`, `obtain a token` and `have a token` into a single `have obtained a token from a service`.

```
  Scenario: Customers join a service
    Given the customers have obtained a token from a service
    Then open a url and apply the token
```